# E0277 "Sized is not implemented for the type [u8]", but my type does not have a [u8]

Tags: rust

I'm making a `Node` tree. Here is the code:

```
use std::option::Option;
use std::path;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum NodeType {
    Binding((String, String)),
    Header,
    Include(path::Path),
    Raw(String),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node {
    node_type: NodeType,
}

impl Node {
    fn new() -> Node {
        Node { node_type: NodeType::Header }
    }
}
```

When I compile this, I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied in `std::path::Path`
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
8 |     Include(path::Path),
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ within `std::path::Path`, the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[u8]`
  |
  = note: `[u8]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  = note: required because it appears within the type `std::path::Path`
  = note: only the last field of a struct may have a dynamically sized type
```

I searched for this error, but it seems to refer to an type where `Sized` is not implemented. Oddly, the error output says that `[u8]` does not implement `Sized`, but there's not even one `u8` in my code. What could it be?

Comment: Style point: an empty `new` is better expressed by implementing the `Default` trait's `default` method. It also makes your type default-constructible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that your `NodeType` enum contains a [`std::path::Path`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html) in its `Include` variant, but `Path` is an unsized type (because it contains a `[u8]` indirectly, and `[u8]` is unsized, hence the error you get).

To fix this, change the `Include` variant to contain either a `&Path` (if the node should borrow the path) or a [`PathBuf`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html) (if the node should own the path), or else change `Node::new()` to return `Box<Node>`.

Changing `Include` to contain a `&Path` requires adding a lifetime parameter to `Node` and to `NodeType`. The concrete lifetime may be static when the enum is not an `Include`.

The code below demonstrates how this would work. Note how there are two `impl` blocks for `Node`: the first one (`impl Node<'static>`) should contain all methods that don't use the lifetime parameter, while the second one (`impl<'a> Node<'a>`) should contain all methods that do use the lifetime parameter (that includes all methods with a `self` parameter).

```
use std::path;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum NodeType<'a> {
    Binding((String, String)),
    Header,
    Include(&'a path::Path),
    Raw(String),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<'a> {
    node_type: NodeType<'a>,
}

impl Node<'static> {
    fn new() -> Node<'static> {
        Node { node_type: NodeType::Header }
    }
}

impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    fn include(path: &'a path::Path) -> Node<'a> {
        Node { node_type: NodeType::Include(path) }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I turn Path into a reference to Path (&Path) the compiler asks me for a lifetime.

Comment: I understood everything except for using `'static` as lifetime. What does it?

Comment: `'static` means that the referent is available for the whole program's lifetime. However, in `Node::new()`, the enum I return doesn't actually store a reference, so since you can't get a reference out of that enum, any lifetime is valid. Now, I just tested, and I thought putting `new()` in the generic `impl` block would raise an error about the compiler being unable to infer a lifetime for `'a`, but that's not true (it would have been true if it had been a type parameter, though).

Comment: Is there any way to figure this out except by removing members and/or recursively drilling down on every [remaining] member of the flagged `struct` until you see an element of the offending type?  Like, how would you otherwise know (in a complex `struct`) which is the offending member (and thus which requires a lifetime)?

Comment: @jhfrontz I've seen some situations where the compiler will give you a stack of types leading to an unsatisfied bound, but unfortunately this doesn't appear to be one of them. Only the last field of a `struct` may have a dynamically sized type, so that should help narrow down the search.